# RBAC authorization when using Helm charts on Terraform

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, rbac

I am attempting to create an nginx-ingress server using Helm charts on Terraform. I have run into this error:

Error: failed to create resource: clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "id-00722-service-account@mucius-storm200722.iam.gserviceaccount.com" cannot create resource "clusterroles" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope: requires one of ["container.clusterRoles.create"] permission(s).

My issue seems extremely similar to those experienced here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/77.

But in trying to implement the various solutions in that thread I ran into a few problems. For example, Terraform’s helm provider no longer accepts the service_account argument. Or when I tried to implement Tiller cluster role bindings I had the same permissions issue. Theoretically I would like my main.tf to look like this:

```
provider "helm" { 

  alias = "my_cluster" 

  kubernetes { 

    config_context_cluster = google_container_cluster.default.name 

    load_config_file       = false 

    host                = "https://${data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.endpoint}" 

    token                  = data.google_client_config.default.access_token 

    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate) 

  } 

} 

  

resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress" { 

  provider      = helm.my_cluster 

  name          = "nginx-ingress" 

  chart         = "./stable/nginx-ingress" 

}
```

If anyone is able to shed light on how I might be able to get around this issue I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried using the kubernetes provider to create the cluster role binding and than use helm for the rest with a depends_on for the crb?

Comment: You should use helm 3.x if at all possible. It does not use Tiller so eliminates that configuration point.